# UIScrollView determine scroll direction on scrollViewDidEndDragging when paging

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Does anyone know how to determine which direction a scroll view will move when the user lifts their finger, i.e. when scrollViewDidEndDragging gets called?

Specifically, when the scroll view is set to paging.

Most of the time, I can just track and check the contentOffset in scrollViewDidScroll, however, there are special cases where the user flicks the screen quickly. In some cases a LEFT-RIGHT-LEFT move will scroll to the next page, and in others, the same pattern will remain on the same page.

I'm guessing it has something to do the with acceleration (difference between the last few points) of the touch.

(I'm on iOS4.3 on an iPad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one,  iOS 5 has the [answer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging%3awithVelocity%3atargetContentOffset%3a), but that no good for you.

Perhaps a hacky workaround is to set a `NSTimer` for a small time interval (say 0.1 seconds) after `scrollViewDidEndDragging` finished. Then compare the content offsets.

If you want to know if the scroll view will actually go to the next page, perhaps you could check if the content offset has gone more than 1/2 way.  You could read the content offset on [`scrollViewDidScroll:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) and do a bit of maths to determine if its more than 1/2 way.

Comment: The iOS 5 answer looked like the solution .... except its not called when paging is enabled! I did think of the timer approach but I was hoping for a less hacky solution. I may try and work around it some other way, if not I'll give the timer approach a go. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't use timer, which is very expensive operation. Lock the direction of your scrollView first to move only up/down and left/right [I guess that's what you want]. And then use following code to determine...

```
CGPoint start, end;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    start = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)sender willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    end = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {    
    NSLog(@"%d %d",(int)start.x,(int)start.y);
    NSLog(@"%d %d",(int)end.x,(int)end.y);
}
```

Comment: if the user was to drag 2cm to the right and then 1cm to the left.. it would give the wrong direction, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution works fine for me hope it helps

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

   CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

   //Old Solution
   //Switch the indicator when more than 30% of the previous/next page is visible
   //You can vary the percentage
   //int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth * 0.3) / pageWidth) + 1;


   //New Solution
    _pageControl.currentPage = (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x / (int)pageWidth;
}
```

I quit the old solution as the new one seems more slick

Comment: The old solution is good, it is handy, when there are totally 31 cells and 5 cells are displayed per page. So the last page will show cells from index to 26 to 30. (index 30 means it is the 31st cell). In this case my factor to multiply would be 1/5 (because there are 5 cells per page)

Answer (score 2):

Implement the following UIScrollViewDelegate Method.
You can compare current content offset and targetContentOffset then get the direction.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{

    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(targetContentOffset->x, targetContentOffset->y);

    if (newOffset.x > scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling direction is left");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Scrolling direction is right");
    }

}
```

Comment: The velocity can be 0, it will set to "Right" in wrong moments with your solution.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saurin response.
Her solution work fine but if you are using pagination and you are in the end of scroll content size you will have to test if we really have a scroll to the next 'page' or not:

```
CGPoint start, end;

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    start = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    end = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (start.x > end.x && end.x>0)
   {
       NSLog(@"on the previous left page");
   }

   if (start.x < end.x && end.x < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
   {
       NSLog(@"on the next right page");
   }
}
```

Comment: If the user scroll in zigzag then stop when moving to right after started a bit more to the right in comparison with the actual position it will give the wrong result. Always do the "crazy monkey test" when testing a interface ;)